# Is there any strong support for SQL database to persist rabbitmq message

Tags: sql, rabbitmq, persistent, durability

We have achieved persistent mechanism with activemq as it has built in support to store messages in SQL database.

But our requirement to store message in SQL using rabbitmq but after some research we are unable to find any strong support or help for this.

Any suggestion would be great help to us.

Comment: I'd suggest you just build it. Spring is nice or Apache camel (both Java).

Answer (score 2):

RabbitMQ uses `Mnesia` DB to store the definitions about queues/exchanges etc. and it uses a custom DB to store the messages.

Right now, with RabbitMQ is not possible to use an external database to store the messages as ActiveMQ

maybe in the future.

Comment: Thanks Gabriele for your answer.